# Runtime Error encountered while running on Online Judges

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime-error

I have been solving [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/) problem on SPOJ . One of the most frequent problems encountered while using online judges is `Runtime Error`. You never know which case leads to a `Segmentation fault`. Please help me figure out why does the code below correspond to a `Runtime Error` or `Segmentation Fault` even though I have ensured that every possible case runs properly on my linux gcc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int t,i;
    cin >> t;
    string s;
    vector<int> A;


    while(t--)
    {   

        cin >> s;
        int n=s.size();
        int temp;

        if (n!=1) 
        {
            for(i=0;i<s.size();i++)
            {
                A.push_back(s.at(i)-'0');
            }

            if(n%2!=0)
                {   i = (n-1)/2;

                    while(A[i-1]==A[n-i])
                        i--;

                    i--;
                }

            else
                {   i=n/2-1;

                    while(A[i]==A[n-1-i])
                        i-- ;       
                }


            if (A[i]<A[n-i-1])
                {   
                    if ((n%2)!=0)
                        {
                            A[n/2] = A[n/2] + 1;
                            A[n-i-1] = A[i];
                        }
            else
                {
                    A[n/2-1] = A[n/2-1]+1;
                    A[n/2] = A[n/2-1];
                    A[n-i-1] = A[i]; 
                }
            }

            else
                A[n-i-1] = A[i];

            while(i--)
                A[n-i-1] = A[i];



            while(!(A.empty()))
            {
                printf("%d",A.back());
                A.pop_back();
            }
        }

        else
            cout << s;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Hi @VaibhavBajaj , done !

Comment: Do you get error text?  If so, please post that.

Comment: @donjuedo Why don't you hard-code the input into your post that you claim works?  We don't care about the number of test cases.  In other words post a [mcve], not what you give to SPOJ verbatim.

Comment: @sakshamjindal Asking about online code judges is futile here, since no one knows all of their undisclosed test cases, or other inner workings.

Comment: @donjuedo There seems to be no error encountered when it is made to run on my machine (Linux gcc 4.8) . But if the same code is submitted to an online judge (here SPOJ and codechef) , error pops up `Runtime-Error` . I have tested it on my machine for a lot of cases.

Comment: @sakshamjindal - Again, please post the input you say "works".  An out-of-bounds access (which could be likely in your code) causes *undefined behavior*.  For that, you could have used `at()` instead of `[ ]` in your vector accesses.  This would reveal if your test cases you say works actually do work.

Comment: Hi @πάνταῥεῖ ! My bad ! Asking it on Stackoverflow is the last thing I did before exhausting all sources of information.  In future , I will keep that in mind

Comment: @sakshamjindal Well, asking at Stack Overflow never was meant as your _least resort personal help-desk_, Sorry.

Comment: @sakshamjindal -- You say you tried the test cases and saw no error.  That is not what happens [here](http://ideone.com/j3D2dz).  A runtime error occurs on the very first test case.  That's why I asked you for the test case, but I took one for the team and plugged it in, and lo and behold, it doesn't work.  Using `at()` reveals the mistake [here](http://ideone.com/kJrFqj).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hey , initially I thought that something wrong is with the way I am using C++ (new to vectors and STL ; you only advised me to adopt vectors instead of array ; It was the last time I asked a question) . But thought over and found that I missed a lot of cases . For example : I finput is 9 or the central digit is 9 . These are few of the left out cases . I really don't think that it has something to do with  `at()` .

Answer (score 0):

I found one of your problems for segmentation fault , when you give for example "aaaaa" input to s you will get segmentation fault on this part of code

```
if(n%2!=0)
            {   i = (n-1)/2;

                while(A[i-1]==A[n-i])
                    i--;

                i--;
            }
```

because you didn't check i < 0 or not